# Error in retrieving facebook data

Tags: android

I am trying to get email and user name from the facebook in my application, So I have written the necessary code with in my fragment. After Clicking the Login button it fetching the data and asking for the permission to fetch data from the facebook. After ok it throws an exception that

```
  Error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to open a session that has a pending request.
```

The code I am using is (I have tried with onActivityResult())

```
 public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {


LoginButton loginWithFBButton;


 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, container, false);

    loginWithFBButton  = (LoginButton)v.findViewById(R.id.authButton);

    loginWithFBButton.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener(){

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
            }

          });

          // set permission list, Don't forget to add email
    loginWithFBButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email"));
          // session state call back event
    loginWithFBButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                      Log.i(TAG,"Access Token"+ session.getAccessToken());
                      Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                              new Request.GraphUserCallback() {


                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                        Response response) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                     Log.i(TAG,"User ID "+ user.getId());
                                     Log.i(TAG,"Email "+ user.asMap().get("email"));
                                }
                              });


                  }
            else if (state.isClosed()) {

            }
        }
          });

        return v;
 }

    public void startActivityForResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

}

Comment: Do you have properly configured your app on the page Facebook Developers? Example: Name package, keyhash, etc..

Comment: yeah..I had configured all that stuff

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change to:

```
    public void startActivityForResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

to

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Comment: I have tried that, no result actually then I roll it back

Comment: I think not calling the method "onActivityResult()" of the fragment if not this calling the activity. Try check Log.d() if it is calling in onActivityResult() of fragment.

Comment: Its not entering to onActivityREsult()